# Accessing qemu multicast networks (from Docker containers)

Tags: networking, docker, qemu, multicast

QEMU [allows](https://people.gnome.org/~markmc/qemu-networking.html) to connect different VMs by using a virtual network based on a common multicast address by specifying `-netdev socket,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234` on startup.

This way I can easily connect multiple VMs and join new VMs on the fly.

Is it possible to join that network **without** using QEMU? Especially is it possible to connect a docker container to that network?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running the VMs on a single host and not on multiple hosts, the simplest way to make a network between the QEMU VMs and other VMs (or real hosts) is to use tap devices instead of multicasting, then bridge the tap devices, and add your Docker container interfaces (or whatever you fancy) to the bridge.

BTW, the syntax and network description in the link you gave is [obsolete](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#The_legacy_-net_option) and will go away at some stage. In particular the concept of QEMU vlans will go away. In current syntax, use something like

```
-netdev tap,ifname=qemu0
```

and then (as root)

```
ip link add br_qemu type bridge
ip link set br_qemu up
ip link set qemu0 master br_qemu
ip link set qemu1 master br_qemu
```

etc. If you create the bridge before you launch the VMs, you can also use `-netdev bridge,br=br_qemu` to make QEMU add the tap interfaces to the bridge.

If you specifically need multicast because your VMs are running on different physical hosts, then it's going to be more complicated. The first step would be to figure out the format in which QEMU sends the packets (it's not the raw packet, but I haven't looked further), and the second to write a proxy that joins the multicast group, and forwards between this group and a tap interface.

Alternatively (but less efficiently), you could run a dedicated QEMU VM with two network cards, one multicast and one tap, which is configured to do nothing but forward between them.

An even better alternative would be to implement communcation between the different physical hosts in a different way (tunnel, VLANs over the physical LAN (real 801.q VLANs, not QEMU ones)), and stick to the tap interfaces.

**Edit**

To add a VLAN to your LAN, say on `eth0` in the host, just do

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.5 type vlan id 5
```

where `5` is the VLAN tag you have chosen. Next, add this interface to the bridge

```
ip link set eth0.5 master br_qemu
```

and you are good to go. You can put these two commands in a script you use to start the VMs. Alternatively, put the equivalent of this into `/etc/network/interfaces` (google or read manpage for details). Yes, it does require a tiny bit of configuration in the host.

**Edit**

Ok, I had a look at the format of the multicast packets QEMU sends, and it's just the ethernet frame. So you can do something like

```
socat UDP4-DATAGRAM:230.0.0.1:1234,sourceport=1234,ip-add-membership=230.0.0.1:10.0.0.2 TUN:10.2.3.1/24,tun-type=tap,iff-no-pi,iff-up
```

on the host that has the docker container, where `10.0.0.2` is a valid IP address for the host with respect to the multicast group, e.g. the IP address of `eth0`. This will give you a `tap` (level 2) interface where you can send ethernet packets to and receive them from the multicast group. Now you only have to bridge/route those to your Docker container.

Instead of `socat`, you can also write your own short C program etc., if you want and think it's more efficient.

Comment: I am aware of  `-netdev tap`. However the goal is to connect VMs running on different hosts, which might come and go dynamically. Therefore it looks like `-netdev socket,mcast` is the only good solution.

Comment: I'm also aware of the obsolete syntax in the linked text. Are you aware of any resource talking about `mcast` and the `netdev` syntax?

Comment: A VLAN-tag would work perfectly fine with VMs running on different hosts, which might come and go. But if you don't want that and insist on mcasts, you'll have to decide between putting in effort to figure out the protocol, or running a dedicated VM as a proxy, as I wrote. Your choice :-)

Comment: The man page currently has both the old `-net` and the new `-netdev` syntax.

Comment: Can you add an example how to use VLAN-tags with qemu? The nice thing with mcast is, that it does not require any fancy configuration on the host. (I'm trying to make use of the idle workstations of my coworkers and don't want them to reconfigure their network setup.)